# iText encrypting a digitally signed PDF

Tags: cryptography, itext, digital-signature

I did an encryption/decryption of a PDF document using the PdfWriter setEncryption. Everything is working fine and the decryption is OK.

When I did the same for a digitally signed PDF document I have the digital information corrupted with the message (SigDict/Contents illegal data)

Is it possible to encrypt a PDF without affecting the digital sign information?

Answer (score 2):

Encryption involves rewriting complete stream. If your PDF is digitally signed, this will break the digital signature, hence it is impossible (**in general**, not limited to iText) to encrypt a PDF that is digitally signed (unless breaking the signature is acceptable).

You need to encrypt the document before signing or at the moment of signing. Never encrypt a PDF *after* signing.